Securing Artifactory 7.x UI using HTTPS
I recently upgraded my Artifactory instance to 7.84.15.  Currently to access the UI I have to go to: http://localhost:8082/ui/.  I'd like to make the UI accessible via HTTPS, so I could access it via something like: https://artifactory.example.com/ui/. I looked at the documentation for securing the microservices: https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-functionality-and-usage-of-tls-in-artifactory/artifactory-functionality-and-usage-of-tls-in-artifactory but there doesn't seem to be anything to allow me to change the port for the UI to 443. How can I secure the UI behind HTTPS using just Artifactory?  Do I have to use a reverse proxy?

We can do SSL offloading at the Nginx layer so that the UI can be accessible over HTTPS and 443 port. You may use the configuration mentioned in the below documentation: https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/set-up-the-nginx-server-using-http-or-https
If you wish to configure TLS at the Artifactory application level, then follow the steps mentioned under the section "Steps to enable TLS on Artifactory:" of below documentation: https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-functionality-and-usage-of-tls-in-artifactory
